# GeoWebCache: misalignment of tiles

Tags: web-mapping, openlayers-2, geoserver, geowebcache

I'm trying to test simple web map based on PostGIS/Geoserver/OpenLayers stack on Windows Server 2008.

When I load my WMS layer by:

```
var gwctest = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "gwctest",
    "http://localhost:1979/geoserver/wms",
    {
    'layers': 'Index2000:index_vect_s100',
    'format': 'image/png',
    'srs': 'EPSG:3857', 
    'units': 'm',
    'transparent': true
    },
    {'opacity': 0.8, 'isBaseLayer': false, 'visibility': false}

);
```

Everything seems to be fine.

[image]

However, when I try to add WMS layer to my map using GeoWebCache, replacing

```
"http://localhost:1979/geoserver/wms"
```

with:

```
"http://localhost:1979/geoserver/gwc/service/wms"
```

My data suddenly move from correct position:

[image]

Any ideas on what may be the cause?

EDIT: some additional info on GWC mailing list [post](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=A83C532A23D1BB4B874F48AD3013F433037924C5717E%40EX2K7-CCR.AAD.GOV.AU&forum_name=geowebcache-users).

Comment: It looks like a datum shift issue. You may need to edit your projection to_wgs parameters if your wms is being reprojected. http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms#towgs84-DatumtransformationtoWGS84

Comment: @geographika: Why would then the same layer display correctly without GWC mode then?

Comment: It uses a different config file for projections? See http://geoserver.org/display/GEOSDOC/5.+GWC+-+GeoWebCache

Comment: @geographika: I presume it's an old version of GeoServer docs. Newer version: http://geoserver.org/display/GEOSDOC/5.+GWC+-+GeoWebCache. My GeoWebCache Configuration page says the tiles are ready in 3857 projection, and this is proj used by my web map as well.

Comment: did you ever solve your issue?
I am having a similar issue with a greater shift. I see that geographika talsk about a post with causes end solution in the GWC forum, but I don´t find that post.

Comment: This should likely be a comment, as it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/71523)

Comment: @user28386 nfortunately, I abandoned the project without solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

See responses to Radek's post in the GWC forum for actual cause and solution. I now understand why TileCache opted for displaying errors such as "Current x value -1311047.936977 is too far from tile corner x -1493907.560000" rather than passing back the "closest" tiles within an arbitary error range.

---

Is your original data in EPSG 3857? If not then it is almost certainly a datum shift (not) happening somewhere.

Try changing your OpenLayers definition to reference EPSG:900913 - maybe GeoWebCache doesn't recognise the new web mercator code?

From the link you posted:

> The integrated version of GeoWebCache
>   automatically configures every layer
>   with the two most common projections:
>
> ```
> * EPSG:4326 (standard Latitude/Longitude)
> * EPSG:900913 (Spherical Mercator, the projection used in Google Maps)
> ```
>
> If you need additional projections you
>   can create a configuration file called
>   geowebcache.xml  in the cache
>   directory, for example 
>   /var/geoserver_data/gwc/geowebcache.xml

That sounds as though Geoserver and GeoWebCache use different projection files. Maybe your Geoserver has a to_wgs parameter and GWC doesn't.

As you are on Windows run Process Monitor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 to see which files you are really accessing.

Also I presume the images weren't cached after you changed some projection parameters? Try reseeding / deleting to check.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the original data is in 3857. Seems like GWC recognizes this code: in GWC Demos section there are all three projections available to use: 3857, 4326, 900913. And for the purpose of my map I'm using 3857. Also tried it with 900913 and error remains.

Comment: If your original data is in 3857 without a datum shift then I'd imagine no reprojection takes place in GWC, and your original data needs to be reprojected again.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the correct tile-origin set for your OpenLayers.Map as in GeoWebCache. Check how the TileOrigin is set in the GeoWebCache-demo of the layer and make sure you have the same TileOrigin on your OpenLayers.Map Constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried setting it as: "tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom" where maxExtent is set according to GWC demo of the layer. Still not correct.

Comment: What are your GWC settings, you may need to adjust DPI settings in either GWC or OpenLayers

Comment: I tried adjusting DPI settings according to GWC demo preview of the layer. Didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Misalignment such as this is almost always a projection issue.  Is the data stored in EPSG:3857?  Check that the GeoWebCache layer is configured to output in EPSG:3857.

Comment: Yes, dataset is in 3857 and GWC is also configured for it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes, I did.